# When making API call LiveData returns old value first and then the new one

Tags: android, api, repository, viewmodel, android-livedata

I am using `LiveData` and `RoomDB` and my problem is that when I put the `observe()` on my `LiveData` and then make the request to fetch updates from the server, it first gives me the previous value that it had requested before and then once the request is done it gives me the new value that it got from the server.

When no previous request have been made it works like I want it to, meaning it will fetch the data straight from the server and then show it, but when a request was previously made and the `LiveData` already had a value then it will first show the old one and then the new one.

What I want is for it to show only the new one.

The variables (`viewModel`, `repository`, etc) are coming from dagger.

Main Activity:

```
viewModel.getPointGeoLocation(changedyPoints.get(0)).observe(this, new Observer<LatLng>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable LatLng latLng) {
                    if (latLng != null) {...} else {...}}});
```

ViewModel Class:

```
public LiveData<LatLng> getPointGeoLocation(Point Point) {
    repository.fetchGeoLocationCoordinates(Point);
    return repository.getPointGeoLocationNetworkSource();
}
```

RepositoryImpl Class:

```
@Override
public void fetchGeoLocationCoordinates(Point Point) {
    pointNetworkDataSource.fetchGeoLocations(point);
}    

@Override
public LiveData<LatLng> getPointGeoLocationNetworkSource() {
   return pointNetworkDataSource.getPointGeoLocationData();
}
```

NetworkDataSource Class:

```
public void fetchGeoLocations(Point point) {
    executors().getNetworkIO().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AuthTokenUtil.waitForAuthToken(authTokenRepository);
            AuthToken authToken = authTokenRepository.getAuthToken().getValue();
            if (authToken.isValid()) {
                pointBackendApi.getGeoLocations(authToken.getToken(), point,
                        new PointBackendApi.GeoLocationHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void update(LatLng latLng) {
                                pointGeoLocationData.postValue(latLng);
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "invalid auth token");
            }
        }
    });
}

public LiveData<LatLng> getPointGeoLocationData() {
    return pointGeoLocationData;
}
```

And Finally the Backend API:

```
@Override
public void getGeoLocations(String token, Point point, GeoLocationHandler geoLocationHandler) {
    http.getJson(POINT_GET_GEO_LOCATION_UPDATE, token, point.domesticAddress.formattedString, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) {
            try (ResponseBody body = response.body()) {
                if (body == null || body.contentLength() == 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "received no response");
                    return;
                }

                String res = body.string();
                LatLng result = new Gson().fromJson(res, LatLng.class);
                if (result != null && (result.latitude != 0 && result.longitude != 0)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "received" + " points" + result.toString());
                    geoLocationHandler.update(result);
                } else {
                    geoLocationHandler.update(null);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Received 0, 0 coordinates");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage() != null ? ex.getMessage() : "HTTP problem");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "get failed");
        }
    });
}
```

So basically If I have had a response with value `null` before and then call this API again it will first return `null` and then return the correct response.

The first method `viewModel.getPointGeoLocation()` is called multiple times so that might be the issue but for me it seems that it needs to be inside of the method and act when the button is clicked because the method it is in contains a lot of data that the `onChanged()` should use.

Comment: you get the solution? cause I having the same issue

Comment: I think the answer was to create a custom LiveData class. I will try to find it soon

Comment: Yeah I am also getting the same issue of my old data being returned before the fetch to the API is completed